# Truffle Console: "undefined" message varaiable declaration

Tags: truffle, accounts

I am giving following commands at Truffle console but I am getting "undefined" message:

```
> $ truffle console
> 
> You can improve web3's peformance when running  Node.js versions older
> than 10.5.0 by   installing   the (deprecated)  scrypt package in your
> project 
> 
> truffle(ganache)> let accounts =await web3.eth.getAccounts()
> 
> undefined
```

Truffle version is:

```
> truffle(ganache)> truffle version 
> 
> Truffle v5.1.27 (core: 5.1.27)
> 
>  Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js) Node v8.10.0 Web3.js v1.2.1
> 
>  truffle(ganache)>
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: The `undefined` printed in the console is from the use of `let`. If you examine the variable `accounts` it was correctly assigned.

For example type `let a = 22` and it will print `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the accounts of ganache using JavaScript in truffle console 
I advise you to write the following snippet

```
Web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err,res){accounts=res});
```

and then you can access the list of accounts in truffle console using the following command

```
accounts
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to get all the accounts but then I typed "acc1 = accounts[0]" at the console and it worked.